# How to access bundle that AccountManager.newChooseAccountIntent returns?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am using the intent `newChooseAccountIntent` to have a user pick an account. I read here that the intent returns a bundle with the keys `KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME` for account name and `KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE` for account type.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html

My question is how do I access the bundle the intent returns? Would I do `data.getBundleExtra()` in my activity result function?

Activity result function code

```java
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      Log.d("frag", "is return empty " + data.getBundleExtra("KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME"));
    }
    else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
      Log.d("frag", "intent fired and something went wrong");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Javadoc, both [AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME) and [AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE) are strings, meaning you use `getStringExtra()`:

```
if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    String name = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
    String type = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE);
    Log.d("frag", "Got " + name + ", " + type);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! Kinda new to Android your help is greatly appericated